# Nesting operators in Windows cmd (.bat)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to tidy up some code. Right now I have:

```
SET VAR=%TIME:.=&rem.%
SET VAR=%VAR:,=&rem.%
SET VAR=%VAR::=_%
```

And it works, but I wuld like to turn it into one-liner. Something like this (doesn't work):

```
SET VAR=% % %TIME:.=&rem% :,=&rem.% ::=_%
```

Can I achieve something like this with concise, simple syntax?

Comment: why  not just chain them using `&&` like `set something && set another &&...`

Comment: I don't want obfuscate code. I would like to have readable one line setting for each variable. That's why I'm looking for some shortened (yet readable) syntax. Maybe like `SET VAR = %.. :... :... :...%` or nesting. I don't see anything similar (possibly doesn't exist, but I'm not an expert).

Comment: you seemed to have missed my comment.. `set VAR=%TIME:.=&rem.% && set VAR=%VAR:,=&rem.% && set VAR=%VAR::=_%`

Comment: The quick answer is: no, this is not possible; not even with nested `call set` commands...

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Thank you, I saw it. I tried to do something "more pretty" (IMO) then using many comands in one line.

Comment: @aschipfl Thank you, I suspected it (I couldn't find a solution), but it's nice to be sure. I tried earlier `CALL` but also no luck.

Comment: IMHO this is what you are looking for: `for /F "delims=.," %%a in ("%time::=_%") do set "VAR=%%a"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is possible to do it in one line ([delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) needed), I don't think, it serves readability:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=%time:~0,8%" & set "var=!var::=_!"
echo %var%
```

I suggest moving the formatting to a subroutine. (Not exactly a one-liner, but keeps your main code clean and readable).

```
@echo off
call :FormatTime var="%time%"
echo %var%
goto :eof

:FormatTime
  set "_=%~2"
  set "_=%_:~0,8%"  :: get 'HH:MM:SS'
  set "_=%_: =0%"   :: replace ' ' with '0' 
  set "%1=%_::=_%"  :: replace ':' with '_' 
goto :eof
```

The `call` defines the variable name for the result (`var` here) and the string to format (`%time%` here). Usually, the two arguments are separated by a space, but as `=` also acts as a standard delimiter, we can use that to make the line even more readable (intuitive).
Enclosing the string in quotes (`"%time%`) enables us to catch the space (`" 8:12:00,99"`) to be able to replace it with a zero.

I also used another method to strip the milliseconds part (language independent).

Comment: So do you think that a variable called `_` (underscore) is _readable_? **`:/`**

Comment: @Aacini I'm sure, I said `keeps your *main code* ... readable`... I often use `_` as a temporary variable in subroutines, being sure, I don't overwrite any vital variables anywhere else.